# Python Script monitor for file change

Tags: python, file, freebsd

I want to run a little python script on my Freenas inside a Jail.

The script should watch out for a file. If this file is changed. It should do something.

So my question is what is the mechanism which allows me to monitor a file and run a method when the file is changed (In detail the content of one specific file) or is there another method to just call a python script in such a case.

Comment: `pyinotify` or `inotify-tools` according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12582773/320220

Comment: As far as I know there is no inotify for freebsd or is there?

Comment: changed in which way?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to monitor one special file and do something when the file content is modified.

Comment: Well, you could compare it's content to the previous version every few seconds... It seems pretty straightforward, so what's stopping you? Do you need this to be event based? Realtime? Without more information answering correctly can be tricky.

Comment: So only if the content changes?

Comment: @TM90 Woops, quite right! I didn't notice it was non-linux, sorry!

Comment: @ReutSharabani The most elegant solution would be an event based one.

Comment: @TM90 I think that an update to the file is different than re-creation of the file, so that's information that needs to be included in the question.

Comment: You could try [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) which claims to support BSD.

Comment: There is also http://entrproject.org/

Comment: I will take a look at watchdog and entr. Additionally I also found Kqueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's job for `kqueue`. There are 2 possible bindigs for that... `py-kqueue` (all BSDs and OSX) and `py-freebsd` (just FreeBSD). Both in ports. Some hint how to use `kqueue` here: [Check if file is modified deleted or extended using python select.kqueue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958397/check-if-file-is-modified-deleted-or-extended-using-python-select-kqueue/)

Other example to understand `kqueue` in `py-openbsd` bindings docs: [kqueue - openbsd](https://github.com/cortesi/pyopenbsd/blob/master/doc-src/kqueue.html). And then of course `man kqueue`.

Further option is to use `Twisted` async framework (which in background will use `kqueue` for reactor) and its [FileMonitoringService](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/api/twisted.mail.mail.FileMonitoringService.html). This is periodic checker, generic implementation - OS agnostic.